# How to get a proper update of a binding object from a angular component instantiates a first time with an empty object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been trying Angular components for a few days now and I have an issue.

I've got a navbar with a user object bind by a parent component app (that contains's it). When I login to the app, everything works fine, but if I logout and login again, my user's informations are not displaying properly. With a refresh of the page the bug is solved but I really want to understand what's that bug!

Please check my code below.

**navbar.js**

```
((app) => {
app.component("navbar", {
    templateUrl: '/js/components/common/navbar.html',
    bindings: {
        user: '<'
    },
    controller(UserService, $state) {
        angular.extend(this, {
            $onInit() {

            },
            logout() {
                UserService.disconnect().then(() => {
                    $state.go('login')
                })
            }
        })
    }
})
})(angular.module('app.common'))
```

**app.js**

```
((app) => {
app.component('app', {
    templateUrl: 'js/components/common/app.html',
    controller(UserService, $state){
      angular.extend(this, {
          $onInit(){
            UserService.getCurrent().then((user) => {
              this.user = user
            }).catch((err)=>{
              $state.go('login')
            })
          }
      })
    }
})
})(angular.module('app.common'))
```

**app.html**

```
<navbar user="$ctrl.user" />
<div class="container">
  <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

**routes.js**

```
((app) => {
app.config(($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) => {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login')
    $stateProvider.state('app', {
        url: '',
        abstract: true,
        template: '<app />'
    })
})
})(angular.module('app.config'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem by using [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) in my method userService.getCurrent() instead of [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Promise).

Answer (score 0):

I find an hack to solve my problem :

**navbar.js**

```
((app) => {
app.component("navbar", {
    templateUrl: '/js/components/common/navbar.html',
    bindings: {
        user: '<'
    },
    controller(UserService, $state, $timeout) {
        angular.extend(this, {
            $onInit(){
              $timeout(()=>{
                this.user = this.user
              }, 0)
            },
            logout() {
                UserService.disconnect().then(() => {
                    $state.go('login')
                })
            }
        })
    }
})
})(angular.module('app.common'))
```